# Reading file using Event Listener and saving contents to an array

Tags: java, events

```
    class openFileListener implements ActionListener
  {     
    private String[] hex;
    private byte[] data;

    public String[] getHexArray() {
        return hex;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
         // Select file and show the name of file
         wavFileImport.showOpenDialog(openButton);
         File file = wavFileImport.getSelectedFile();
         fileNameField.setText(file.getName());


        //Reading file 
         String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
         Path pathname = Paths.get(path);
            try {
                // read bytedata 
                data = Files.readAllBytes(pathname);
                Path path2 = Paths.get("output.txt");
                Files.write(path2, data);

                //converts it to 2 digit hex
                hex = new String[data.length];
                for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    hex[i]= String.format("%02X", data[i]);
                }
                PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter("output2.txt");
                for(int i = 0; i < hex.length; i++) {
                    pr.println(hex[i]);
                }
                pr.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //works
            for(int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
                System.out.println(getHexArray()[i]);
            }
     }            
  } //end of class



  openFileListener listener = new openFileListener();
  openButton.addActionListener(listener);
 // Should print out stuff???
  System.out.println(listener.getHexArray()[0]);
```

Hello,
I have an event listener JFileChooser that lets me select a file when I press a button.
I then read the file, and try to save the contents in an array.

I want to access hex[] outside of the event listener. In my main().

I believe my variable is out of scope? Not quite sure, I haven't touched Java in a few years, so I apologize in advance if the problem is a very basic concept.

Comment: is getHexArray() not printing anything ? Access & scope all looks correct in your code.

Comment: The getHexArray()[i] in the class prints correctly. However, when I try to call the function outside of the class (aka in main) it does not print correctly. (last line)

Comment: working fine here. what are the error you are getting can you update full code?